# How to exclude certain tables from Oracle datapump export

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, datapump, expdp

I have a large number of user schemas in my Oracle database. I wish to export the table data for these schemas but exclude any tables that are named with the second character an underscore.

For example I wish to export tables `TPI_SUMMARY`, `DFXRRT` and `RTAFF` but exclude `C_NAMES`, `G_BEARS` etc. Basically just want to exclude anything with an underscore as the second character

I am using Oracle data pump:

```
expdp system/xxxxx@string parfile=parfile.par
```

The `parfile` contains :

```
INCLUDE=TABLE:"IN(select table_name from dba_tables where table_name not like '_\_%')" 
EXCLUDE=SCHEMA:"='SYS','SYSTEM','SYSMAN','DBSNMP','OUTLN','APPQOSSYS'"
DIRECTORY=paul_test 
DUMPFILE=infrep_temp1.dmp 
FULL=Y 
LOGFILE=Daily_Backup_infrep_temp1.log
```

I just cannot get this to work. I *think* that the `EXCLUDE` bit is OK but the `INCLUDE` query is wrong. The `DIRECTORY`, `DUMPFILE` and `LOGFILE` are all OK.

I get the following:

```
Export: Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production on Thu May 4 16:41:48 2017  

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.  

Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production  
ORA-39001: invalid argument value  
ORA-39071: Value for EXCLUDE is badly formed.  
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Any ideas? I'm really struggling to get this to work.

Answer (score 3):

The error refers to `EXCLUDE`, not `INCLUDE`:

> ```
> ORA-39071: Value for EXCLUDE is badly formed
> ```

... and it is indeed that which is wrong. You're trying to use equality with multiple values; you just need to use an `IN()` again:

```
EXCLUDE=SCHEMA:"IN('SYS','SYSTEM','SYSMAN','DBSNMP','OUTLN','APPQOSSYS')"
```

But [as it says in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SUTIL/oracle-data-pump-export-utility.htm):

> The `EXCLUDE` and `INCLUDE` parameters are mutually exclusive.

You are allowed to use two `EXCLUDE` clauses though, so you can negate the first `INCLUDE`:

```
EXCLUDE=TABLE:"NOT IN(select table_name from dba_tables where table_name not like '_\_%')" 
EXCLUDE=SCHEMA:"IN('SYS','SYSTEM','SYSMAN','DBSNMP','OUTLN','APPQOSSYS')"
```

or as that's now a double-negative:

```
EXCLUDE=TABLE:"IN(select table_name from dba_tables where table_name like '_\_%')" 
EXCLUDE=SCHEMA:"IN('SYS','SYSTEM','SYSMAN','DBSNMP','OUTLN','APPQOSSYS')"
```

But that `like` doesn't match as you expect; you need to add an `escape` clause, and in this context you need to escape the backslash by doubling it up:

```
EXCLUDE=TABLE:"IN(select table_name from dba_tables where table_name like '_\_%' escape '\\')"
```

or you could use `substr()` instead:

```
EXCLUDE=TABLE:"IN(select table_name from dba_tables where substr(table_name, 2, 1) = '_')"
```

You could also, if you have a list of schemas you *do* want, use two `INCLUDE` clauses instead - which might be simpler that listing all of the built-in schemas, which can vary.